# What is the most correct way to iterate through characters of a string in go

Tags: string, loops, go

I am newbie at `Go` and I wish to iterate the characters of a string

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a string = "abcd"
    for i, c := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%d %s\n", i, c)
    }
}
```

I want the output to be

```
    0 a
    1 b
    2 c
    3 d
```

but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your question about efficiency (as per the title), or correctness (as per the question)?

Comment: It's about both

Comment: Then the question is probably too broad. It would be better to ask each as a separate question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix the `go vet` and package `fmt` format error messages (type `rune` is an alias for type `int32`):

```
10: Printf format %s has arg c of wrong type rune

0 %!s(int32=97)
1 %!s(int32=98)
2 %!s(int32=99)
3 %!s(int32=100)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oM9D8oNlaAO

A rune is a Unicode code point (character), not a string.

Use `%c` not`%s`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a string = "abcd"
    for i, c := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%d %c\n", i, c)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/LFQPGZ9X5kk

Output:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

---

An example of type `string` UTF-8 variable-length encoding:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a string = "Greece Ελλάδα"
    for i, c := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%2d %c\n", i, c)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Fdgg6UMXAAt

Output:

```
 0 G
 1 r
 2 e
 3 e
 4 c
 5 e
 6  
 7 Ε
 9 λ
11 λ
13 ά
15 δ
17 α
```

---

References:

[Go package fmt documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings).